# File storage not working using jackrabbit from localhost

Tags: php, jackrabbit

I have not much idea about PHPCR.I am doing a sample prototype to store the files into a WebDav server.The code snippet is given below.It's only creating the node.But I want the file to be stored in the server.

```
$jackrabbit_url = 'http://xxxxxxxxxx:8900/jackrabbit/server';
$user           = 'xxxxxx';
$pass           = 'xxxxxx';
$workspace      = 'default';

$factory = new \Jackalope\RepositoryFactoryJackrabbit();
$repository = $factory->getRepository(
    array("jackalope.jackrabbit_uri" => $jackrabbit_url)
);

$credentials = new \PHPCR\SimpleCredentials($user, $pass);
$session = $repository->login($credentials, $workspace);
$node = $session->getNode('/test');


$imageURL ='/var/www/sxnew/phpcr/web/uploads/FolderE/test.png';
$contents = base64_encode(file_get_contents($imageURL));

$image = $node->addNode("test.png");
$image->setProperty("jcr:content", "nt:resource");
$image->setProperty("jcr:data", $contents);
$image->setProperty("jcr:mimeType", "image/png");

$session->save();
```

Please help anybody

Comment: Hey all, anybody knows it, i have been trying so hard.But not getting the proper result